# Get value from option tree wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to be use some sliders in my wordpress theme. I want to select them in my theme option. I am using the code below.

```
<?php 
    $slider_select = get_option_tree( 'slider_select', '', 'true' ); 
?>

<?php get_template_part('$slider_select'); ?>
```

But, it is not working. I want the get_template_part code worked. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
get_template_part('$slider_select');
```

with

```
get_template_part($slider_select);
```

Comment: getting value for '$slider_select = get_option_tree( 'slider_select', '', 'true' );' 

I don't need it. How can I remove the value?

Comment: I am fixing this by CSS. http://s8.postimg.org/ayjp5fuit/screenshot_113.png

is there is anyway for fix by PHP?

Comment: @RaselAhmed, which plugin you use for option tree?

Comment: I am using option tree wordpress plugin. Link: http://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/

Comment: @RaselAhmed, then you can use ot_get_option( <your slider id> ); to get store into value into Slider

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for create a slider in option tree.
create settings array like this.

```
array(
    'id'          => 'my_slider',
    'label'       => 'Images',
    'desc'        => '',
    'std'         => '',
    'type'        => 'list-item',
    'section'     => 'general',
    'class'       => '',
    'choices'     => array(),
    'settings'    => array(
      array(
        'id'      => 'slider_image',
        'label'   => 'Image',
        'desc'    => '',
        'std'     => '',
        'type'    => 'upload',
        'class'   => '',
        'choices' => array()
      ),
      array(
        'id'      => 'slider_link',
        'label'   => 'Link to Post',
        'desc'    => 'Enter the posts url.',
        'std'     => '',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'class'   => '',
        'choices' => array()
      ),
      array(
        'id'      => 'slider_description',
        'label'   => 'Description',
        'desc'    => 'This text is used to add fancy captions in the slider.',
        'std'     => '',
        'type'    => 'textarea',
        'class'   => '',
        'choices' => array()
      )
    )
    )
```

Add into page using loop

```
$my_slider = ot_get_option( 'my_slider' );
    foreach($my_slider as $slider){
        echo '<img src="'.$slider["slider_image"].'">';
        echo $slider["slider_link"];
        echo $slider["slider_description"];
    }
```